# QFileDialog : how to set option to show content of folder in getExistingDirectory()

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8, qfiledialog

I am using `QFileDialog` as

```
filename = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,"Select Image File: ",dataDir,0);
```

I want that I can check files inside folder before selecting it. function `getExistingDirectory()` is setting `QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly` as a default option. I checked in docs there is no any option that do opposite of this. So I set last parameter 0. But now it is not using native dialog. I want to use native dialog with this. I have no clue how to do this cause no flag found in options for UseNativeDialog. Please help.

Comment: In the docs it says "To ensure a native file dialog, ShowDirsOnly must be set."

Comment: Means it is not possible :( should I delete Question?

Comment: I believe there may be a way to work around this limitation on at least some operating systems possibly by subclassing QFileDialog so I would keep the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the file dialog on your own, something like:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
dialog.setDirectory(datadir);
dialog.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

The code by Sebastian should create a native dialog, unless you make a line such as:

```
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
```

However, I have not been able to get this working under Windows, even though the documentation says that the `QFileDialog::Directory` option should display files by default. Not only that, but doing:

```
qDebug() << dir_selector.testOption(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
```

displays false on my system, indicating that there is probably a bug somewhere.